# How to detect edges, the orientation of edges and separate each distinct edge for further individual processing

Tags: python, opencv, image-segmentation, edge-detection

So I have physical folders that have features on the edges that I want to process. My first challenge here would be to isolate each individual folder.

I found this video on [Sobel Edge Detection](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uihBwtPIBxM) that includes example C# code that produces this result:
[image]

It quite reliably finds the right side of each folder as red and left as green.

What I need help with is:

1. How do I produce a similar result in opencv. This can find any edge and show which direction they point. All I can find for sobel in opencv are ones that either do x or y.
2. Using this data how can I segment out each folder without it breaking into pieces or accidentally getting parts of adjacent folders. As you can see they can be slanted and have odd bends at random places.

Comment: For 1, the answer is simple; pass the resulting x and y Sobel images into the [`cv2.cartToPolar()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.2/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gac5f92f48ec32cacf5275969c33ee837d). This will give you a magnitude and orientation image---you can color based on the orientation (but of course that's just for visualization purposes). You could use kmeans with k=2 to segment into the two directions. Not sure if that exactly helps you with problem #2 though.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds thanks. I think I will try detecting the features first (color markings using a mask) and then if I actually run into problems of crossing over into other folders, I'll then look into using edge detection to prevent that. The idea is the folder ID will be encoded using color patterns.